# Tools to find anonymous classes in Java source code

Tags: java, software-development

I want to find anonymous classes in some code to see if they should be changed to lambdas for readability's sake.  Is there any tool which does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## IntelliJ

The [*IntelliJ*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) by [JetBrains](http://www.JetBrains.com/) offers such a feature.

Choose `Edit` > `Find` > `Search Structurally…` > `⚙` (Gear icon menu) > `Existing Templates…` > `Java` > `Class-based` > `anonymous classes`

See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52197416/642706) on Stack Overflow.